# How to chain to a Java 8 Supplier

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

`Supplier` does not provide a `andThen` method, so chaining another `Function` to the result of a `Supplier` is not possible.
Is the only alternative to use a `Function<Void, R>` that does not get any parameter?

In other words, if `Supplier.andThen()` existed I could write:

```
 Supplier<Exception> cleanedExceptionSupplier = exceptionSupplier.andThen( 
     e -> clean(e));
```

Since it does not exist, how can I cleanly implement `cleanedExceptionSupplier`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding my alternate solution as a candidate here

```
Function<Void, R> supplierAsFunction = v -> returnSomethingOfR();

supplierAsFunction.andThen(function).apply(null);
```

Applying `null` as a parameter is rather ugly but this solution maintains functional style while using only `java.util.function` classes.

Comment: Interesting alternate solutions given here, but I'm still sticking to my original solution for functional style readability and use of `java.util.function` classes only.

Comment: So you are in control of both, the `Supplier` creation and the place where it is evaluated, so that you can change the type to `Function`? That renders the whole task a non-existent problem.

Comment: @Holger Yes, this solution is still somewhat awkward because I cannot use a `Supplier`, only a `Function`.

Comment: …and you are still calling `apply` manually. No benefit over `R r = returnSomethingOfR(); X x = function.apply(r);`

Comment: In my view, the benefit is the functional style representation, you naturally read the expression left-to-right in order of execution.

Comment: Read my previous comment again. It *is* read and executed left-to-right. The “functional style representation”, you are trying to achieve, is only a complication. But if you want to do real functional programming, you should become used to the fact that the notation has nothing to do with the order of the evaluation. Otherwise, stay with the imperative notation.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
 Supplier<T> supp2 = supp1.andThen(function);
```

(which, uses a method you've seen doesn't exist)

... you could use:

```
 Supplier<T> supp2 = () -> function.apply(supp1.get());
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but kind of defeats the purpose of functional chaining, in that I want to express a chain of ordered calls from left to right. Your solution reverses that, to read from right to left.

Comment: @danieln True enough, but it has the advantage of existing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier)`.
Having `supplier` that supplies object of type `SomeType` you will get `CompletableFuture<SomeType>`.

Having CompletableFuture you may chain it using methods `thenAccept`, `thenApply` and other.

As a side effect, your program will become more reactive. calling `supplyAsync` will not block. Actualy, you may never block as long as you will not call blocking operation on your `CompletableFuture`.

To I would solve your case as follows:

```
Supplier<Exception> cleanedExceptionSupplier=<some way to get supplier>.
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(cleanedExceptionSupplier).thenAccept(exception -> System.out.println(exception.toString());
```

Side note: it does not look right to me to have `Supplier` of `Exception`. Is exception indeed main effect you want to supply? Or is it  (possibly unwanted) corner case?

Comment: I edited the original question to add that example. I must admit that `Exception` was a completely arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
interface MySupplier<T> extends Supplier<T> {
    <V> V applyTo(Function<T, V> f) {
        return f.apply(get());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MySupplier<Integer> s = () -> 1;
Function<Integer, Integer> f = i -> i + 1;
s.applyTo(f);
```